# How to disable mouse scroll over markers in Bing Maps v7

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing-maps

**Title explains it well.**

I am using "Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 7.0". I successfully disabled the mouse wheel from zooming in and out of the map. However, if I am hovering over a marker(pin) on the map, It still is zooming in and out.

**Below is the code that I used to disabled the mouse wheel:**

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'mousewheel', function(e) {
  if(e.targetType == 'map') {
    e.handled = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code worked fine for me:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.handled = true;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Bing Maps equivalent to setting scrollwheel:false in Google Maps API v3.

Answer (score 2):

For others that may come across this question that want to know how to completely disable zooming (i.e. via the scroll wheel or otherwise) in Bing Maps AJAX API v7, here's how:

> ```
> var options = {
>    credentials: 'put-your-credentials-here',
>    **disableZooming: true**
> ```
>
> }
>
> map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), options);

The Bing Maps API provides other MapOptions, [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx).

Regarding @Mike Henken's problem:

> However, if I am hovering over a marker(pin) on the map, It still is zooming in and out.

That appears to be a bug in Bing Maps v7 API that has been fixed as of 8/5/2013. I can no longer reproduce that problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this bug fix?

Comment: No, I don't have a reference for the bug fix. Perhaps I should have stated simply that I was not able to reproduce @Mike Heneken's problem.

Comment: @VinceHorst What if I don't want to disable zooming completely but only disable it when they are scrolling inside an infobox?  At the moment the map will zoom when I use the mousewheel inside a scrollable infobox and I don't want the map to zoom during this.

Comment: @Fogolicious, perhaps you can use the Bing Maps [Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427623.aspx) method to disable the mouse wheel when the user mouses over and out of the pushpin. Ex: Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseover', someMethodName); and Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'mouseout', someOtherMethodName); (PS: I actively use the above code for handling pushpin events, so I know the concept works.)

Comment: @VinceHorst I just used some jQuery to target the text in the infobox and added `.hover(function(){map.setOptions({disableZooming:true});}, function(){map.setOptions({disableZooming:false});});`